# How I can calculate the endpoint of a line, if I have the starting point, the angle and length of the line?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, raycasting

Point 1, say it is (0, 0) and I have another point that should turn around at a distance of 10f. Then I'll adding degrees angle to make it rotate. I be wanting to know how to calculate that point that this turning around each other ..

I will use the raycasting, I need to rotate the ray (clockwise) to detect collisions

Comment: So the other point will be moved like a projectile? (sorry, I'm not too sure what's happening here)

Comment: I have an actor, hi's rotating around himself "watching" everything. Then I want to know if the line of sight It's collapsing with an body using raycasting. I only have a code for the actor rotation, can be usefull?

Comment: oh, so you want to know if an actor is watching an object having this light like its field of view?

Comment: exactly, that's what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you say you have `point1` and `point2`, both separated by a distance of `10f` where `point2` will be rotating around `point1`, and you want to know if between this separation an object at some point is intersecting them, something like the following image:

[image: view]

There are tutorials to get the maths for rotate a point arount another one in internet, like [this one](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/11/24/GameDev-math-recipes-Rotating-one-point-around-another-point.aspx), and since you can't specify an origin for a `Vector2`, a translated version of the code proposed in the previews link to java should be something similar to:

```java
public Vector2 rotatePoint(Vector2 center, Vector2 point, float angle) {
    angle = angle * MathUtils.degreesToRadians; // Convert to radians
    float rotatedX = MathUtils.cos(angle) * (point.x - center.x) 
            - MathUtils.sin(angle) * (point.y - center.y) + center.x;
    float rotatedY = MathUtils.sin(angle) * (point.x - center.x) 
            + MathUtils.cos(angle) * (point.y - center.y) + center.y;

    // rotated new position:
    return new Vector2(rotatedX, rotatedY);
}
```

As for the rest of the code (the intersection between objects), I guess you are looking for the [`RayCastCallback`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/RayCastCallback.html) interface:

```java
// initial position
Vector2 point1 = new Vector(0, 0);
// Max lenght of view
Vector2 point2 = new Vector(0, 10);
// Position of collision if occur
final Vector2 collisionPoint = new Vector();

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //...
    point2 = rotatePoint(point1, point2, 10); // rotate 10º
    // to detect if object at position point1 is seeing something
    world.rayCast(new RayCastCallback(){
        @Override
        public float reportRayFixture(Fixture fixture,  Vector2 point, 
                 Vector2 normal, float fraction) {
            // what do the object saw?     -> fixture
            // where do the object saw it? -> point

            collisionPoint.set(point);

            return 0; // <- return 0 to stop raycasting
        }
    }, point1, point2);
    //...  rotation and other stuffs...
}
```

The return parameter of [`reportRayFixture`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/RayCastCallback.html#reportRayFixture-com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-float-) have this documentation:

> Called for each fixture found in the query. You control how the ray cast proceeds by returning a float: return -1: ignore this fixture and continue **return 0: terminate the ray cast return fraction: clip the ray to this point** return 1: don't clip the ray and continue. The Vector2 instances passed to the callback will be reused for future calls so make a copy of them!

** Emphasis added.

Basically it says that you can check for all the intersections one by one, but if you care only for the first one, return 0 immediately. This is useful when you want to know if an object is being blocked by another one. In this case, I return 0 and copy the value of `point` to `collisionPoint` to let you do whatever you want to do with this value.

A very nice example can be found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqCz13qWd7A).

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem with this, I just needed to add the radius and now works

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [Intersector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html) class to check if the line from your actor intersects with the body shape.

To calculate end of "sight" line use **Vector2** that you will be rotating according to your actor rotation (which is actually answer for your question)

It should looks like:

```
    Vector2 sightVector = new Vector2(10f, 0); //the 10f is actually your sight max distance
    sightVector.rotate(actor.getRotation());
    
    ...
    
    @Override
    pblic void render(float delta) //it can be also act of the actor
    {
        sightVector.rotate(actor.getRotation());
    
        Vector2 endOfLine = new Vector2(actor.getX() + sightVector.x, actor.getY() + sightVector.y); //here you are calculating the end of line
    
        Polygon bodyShape = getBodyShape( theBody ); //you should create a method that will return your body shape
        
        if( Intersector.intersectLinePolygon(new Vector2(actor.getX(), actor.getY()), endOfLine, bodyShape) )
        {
            //do something
        }
            
        ...
        
    }
```

Intersector has method to check intersection with circles etc also so your body Shape doesn't need to be polygon

Comment: The problem is the line between this two vectors can't transgress some box2d bodies ( walls ), sorry but I didn't say before..